# Complete an open polygon from a KML

Tags: javascript, java, kml, polygon

I am working on an app that tests whether or not a certain coordinate is in the "beam" of a satellite transponder. My code works well except for cases of an open polygon. I was just closing these polygons by adding a coordinate on the end that was the same as the first but that is not a good approach as seen in the cases in the image I attached. The black represents how they are supposed to be completed.
[image: Google Earth Screenshot]

I am parsing a KML that contains these polygons that are in the form of a LinearRing. They are not always counter-clockwise as they are supposed to be so I can't go from that clue.

For the yellow example, I thought about just using the coordinates on the two ends and fixing the longitude and generating latitude values until they matched up.
This approach fails for the blue example because of the pole issue but I could flip 180 degrees once I got to the pole. I also am not sure how to decide to go up in latitude or down. Obviously the semi-circle opens up towards the north so I would go that way but I can't figure out a reliable test for how it opens because of the red example. It mostly opens up toward the north (which is the way it should) but the ends start to go south so I couldn't just test the ends because it would look like it is opening up to the south. Is there a way to test to see what direction a parabola "mostly" opens up towards?

Something that might make it easy is that since it is a geo satellite, it can only see half of the earth centered at 0 degrees latitude. That is why I was thinking of traversing up or down a fixed longitude.

Another thing I was thinking about...could I treat this as a pseudo-cartesian system since I am a satellite looking at half of the earth. It pretty much resembles an skewed x-y system.

My question is, what is the best approach in completing the polygon and preserving the intended beam pattern?

EDIT: I could use the end points to calculate a point between the ends and then get the slope of the bisector using a middle point of the original curve. This would give me the direction of how it opens up.

```
y+, x+ : it opens toward the upper right
y+, x- : it opens toward the upper left
y-, x+ : it opens toward the lower right
y-, x- : it opens toward the lower left
```

From there, I am not sure how to generate the points. Can I just use the longitude of one of the end points and keep that fixed while iterating through latitudes around the globe until it matches the latitude of the other end point? I feel like I am oversimplifying it. I would hate to get it "working" and then realize it was a waste because it only works for a certain test case.

Comment: Can you explain why red is closed upwards while green is closed downwards? Is there a general rule such as "if both ends north of equator close upwards, if both south of equator close downwards"?

Comment: It's just a crude drawing of a certain case of where it mostly is opening upwards but I can't just get the slope at the tips to figure out which direction it opens. Using the slope at the ends, it would appear that it opens down but it mostly opens up. No, there is not a rule about where it is in relation to the equator. I wish

Comment: I do not think this can be answered "in general" - if there are ambiguous cases, such as not being able to know if red closes upwards or downwards, then the problem is ill defined, and users should either provide more input or expect wrong answers for incomplete inputs.

Comment: There are ways to figure out what direction the red (and other cases) would close. I am just not sure on the best. It is also possible that I am going at it all wrong. I'm hoping someone has a trick.

Comment: If there are ways, you should edit the problem to describe them.

Comment: What does the KML with the open Polygons look like?